# Get last price for each month

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I am using google sheets to track a price for each month.

I would like to see in a yearly view, the last added price for the year.

[image]

Find below my example sheet:

[Minimum Viable Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYKFO_mieEsU52bl5O2tx9GcclBMKyWSEelB8lLgi4k/edit?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions how to track the last price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORTN(SORT(TRANSPOSE(B3:5), 2, 0), 99^99, 2, 1, 1),, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! Can you explain your formula? In my real sheet I have some other numbers between the price row and the year row. Does your formula only work with relative values?

Comment: then put those rows into array... instead `B3:5` you can write: `{B3:3; B4:4; B5:5}`. we transpose the range (rows into columns) then we SORT it based on date row (4) eg. 2nd column of range sorted `0` = descending. then we use SORTN. `99^99` means "output all possible rows". `2` = 2nd mode of sortn which will group chosen column. `1` = our chosen column which will be grouped by all unique values (eg. years) and trailing `1` = sort that ascending. then we just INDEX the 3rd column